# Package Django app on OSX as Windows executable

Tags: django, windows, macos, desktop

I created a Django application on my Mac and would like to package it as a Windows desktop application so that my colleagues can run it on their Windows machines with just a few clicks.  Is that possible, or do i need to use a Windows machine?

This question is related to [Compiling django project as a desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172451/compiling-django-project-as-a-desktop-application).

Thanks.

Comment: They can just install python, and run it there. Python works on all platforms.

Comment: Yes, but my colleagues are not programmers.  Instead of requiring them to install Python, Django, pip, and all of the other project dependencies on their machines, i'd like to bundle the app into a simple executable that they can run with just a few clicks.

Comment: No matter what you do, you will still need Python.